# Javascript hide button on button click

Tags: javascript

I want to hide button on click button.
The query id of the screen where I designed the report is 8.
According to this condition, I have a Mail Notification Date field.
When I click the button, I assign the clicked value to the mail notification date, when I refresh the page, the code block works correctly, if the date field is full, I hide the button, but I want to hide the button directly when I click the button, how can I do it.

My code;

```js
else if (query_id == 8) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var table = document.getElementById('tablekit-table-1')
    var tableCount = table.rows.length
    var types = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="col_Mail Bildirim Tarih"]');
    for (var i = 0; i < tableCount - 1; i++) {
      document.getElementById("col_Mail Bildirim_" + i).onclick = function() {
        document.getElementById('col_Mail Bildirim_' + i).children[0].style.display = 'none';
      }
      if (types[i].children[0].innerHTML != "") {
        document.getElementById('col_Mail Bildirim_' + i).children[0].style.display = 'none'
      }
    }

  }, 500);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Change `onclick` to `addEventListener('click', function(event) {...}`. Then inside your click listener function, use the `event` argument to hide the button that was clicked with `event.target.style.display = 'none';`.